# auto search in jqgrid not working

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete

I have a jqgrid like this. But my auto complete is not working please help.
i want to display autosearch but i am using linq to sql and in code behind i am assigning the data source of the autocomplete extender to a list of strings that contain person name. the page is posting back every time the user types a character in the search toolbar but not displaying the auto control.

is there some mistake in the way i am binding the datasource of the autocomplete extender please help  me i am new to this.

```
<cc1:JQGrid ID="grdUserDetails" runat="server" Width="770px" Height="400px"               OnRowSelecting="select">
                <Columns>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="VisitorID" HeaderText="ID"     TextAlign="Left" PrimaryKey="true"
                        Visible="false" Searchable="false">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                     <cc1:JQGridColumn Searchable="true" DataType="String"  SearchType="AutoComplete" SearchControlID="AutoComplete1"
                        DataField="PersonName" Width="200" HeaderText="Person Name">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company Name" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Contact Number" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                    <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="DisplayDate" HeaderText="Visited on" TextAlign="Left">
                    </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerSettings PageSize="50" PageSizeOptions="[50,75,100]" />
                <ToolBarSettings ShowSearchButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="true" ShowSearchToolBar="true">
                </ToolBarSettings>
                <AppearanceSettings ShowRowNumbers="True"></AppearanceSettings>
            </cc1:JQGrid>
<cc1:JQAutoComplete DisplayMode="ControlEditor" DataTextField="Person Name" runat="server"
    ID="AutoComplete1" />
```

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the column setup you can

```
searchoptions: {dataInit: function (elem) { AutoCompleteFunction(elem) }}, ...
```

Then your autocomplete would look something like

```
function AutoCompleteFunction(elem) {    
    $(elem).autocomplete({ source: '/Controller/Action',
        minLength: 2, autosearch: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    })//$(elem).autocomplete
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but i am using ajax toolkit for the same which do u think has a better performance though..??

Comment: I don't know if there would be any real difference as this would just be through jQuery. Please mark ask correct if this worked.